# how to corectly make template function with iterators and user classes

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ and decided do something with templets and iterators.
But when I started trying using my code with my classes it stopt working because I can't use with my classes something like ::iterator what i used in my template function.

```
#include <vector>

template <class Iterator>
struct Page {
    std::vector<Iterator> data;

    auto begin() const { return *data.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return *data.end(); }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct My_struct {
    My_struct(Iterator begin, Iterator end) { /*...*/ }
    /*...*/
};

template <typename C>
My_struct<typename C::iterator> fun(C& c) {
    return { c.begin(), c.end() };
}

int main()
{
    Page<std::vector<int>::iterator> pag;   
    auto b = fun(pag);                      // 

    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> vec;
    auto a = fun(vec);
}
```

> Error E0304
> no instance of function template "fun" matches the argument list  25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My_struct <typename C::iterator>` is the error source, since `Page` has no `iterator` member (`Page::iterator` does not exist).

Also, this

```
auto begin() const { return *data.begin(); }
auto end() const { return *data.end(); }
```

will cause a segmentation fault since there is no elements in the `vector`, therefore you should not be dereferencing the iterarators:

```
auto begin() const { return data.begin(); }
auto end() const { return data.end(); }
```

and in order to make `fun` working, you can use `auto` as return type, and [*template argument deduction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

```
template <typename C>
auto fun(C& c) {
//^^-- auto as return type
    return My_struct{ c.begin(), c.end() };
//         ^^^^^^^^^^---- template argument deduction
}
```

and you will end up with:

```
#include <vector>

template <class Iterator>
struct Page {
    std::vector<Iterator> data;

    auto begin() const { return data.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return data.end(); }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct My_struct {
    My_struct(Iterator begin, Iterator end) { /*...*/ }
    /*...*/
};

template <typename C>
auto fun(C& c) {
    return My_struct{ c.begin(), c.end() };
}

int main()
{
    Page<std::vector<int>::iterator> pag;
    auto b = fun(pag);                      //

    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> vec;
    auto a = fun(vec);
}
```

that should work properly